# Wordsquare Riddle, Again

Tags: riddle, word-square

My first is very wild
You can't pull him out of the hat
My second is the fourth to start
Yet the first to kick the bucket

My third are points
That makes people trust you
My fourth is anything else
Easy is to figure out this clue

Comment: Are all words of 4 letters like last time?

Comment: @Sid they have to be to form a square

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved via collaboration with [@BeastlyGerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil) and [@Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009/sid).

> `H A R E`
>  `A B E L`
>  `R E P S`
>  `E L S E`

Explanations:

> **HARE:** "Wild" suggests an animal. The phrase "pull him off the hat" seems to refer to a magician pulling a rabbit out of a hat, although the grammar is misleading. 
>  
>  **ABEL:** In the book of Genesis in the Old Testament, the fourth human alive was Abel. The bible also says he was also the first person killed. 
>  
>  **REPS:** Short for reputation points. People tend to trust someone who has a positive reputation. 
>  
>  **ELSE:** The clue literally says "something else".

Comment: Collaboration? Are you guys brothers? By the way, can someone correct the grammar? I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: @WilliamNathanael we solved it together in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I see. Glad you guys take this question seriously!